# iOS Draw gps point on live capted video

Tags: ios, gps, avfoundation, core-location

I am trying to draw point on my screen from live captured video like shown image below.

[image: image example]

I am on location XY that I read from phone GPS. I insert two points (GPS) P1 and P2.

How can I show this points (p1, p2) on screen. Same logic like shown in video below (0:45).

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O0qQNo3jp5Q&feature=player_embedded

Does any one know any blog, forum or tutorial that explains how shout I create this or any other suggestion or hint?
The vertical accuracy is not so important as horizontal.

Answer (score 0):

You are talking about "augmented reality"

All in all this is a demanding tasks:

The easy part:
- convert all GPS coordinates into a cartesian meter based coordinate system.
- find out the direction the camera is heading: use built in compass (horicontal azimuth)
- use accelerometer to find out vertical azimut (if camera looks up, or down)

Now more difficult

- find out the tech data / or calibrate the cameras objective (focal length)

With that data, build up a 3d vector world, (e.g a cube with evry 10m a line), and project that to the virtaul camera sensor position in that 3d world (like 3d games do when you csn select camera position).
Them you want to calibrate your camera parameters, such that the simulated world 10m grid lines fit the real world.
Now create the two geo positions as objects in that 3d world, and draw them.

You want to read an imntroduction to 3d computer graphics, and in "augmented" reality.

If you have luck you find a lib for iphone augmented reality.